# Anyone Know What This Is?

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, plant-anatomy

So I don't know much about plant structure or biology in general but I found this little guy while on  X10 and x40 lenses on our school microscope while looking at a leaf. I'm not sure if it's part of the leaf or if it's something that attached to it (I did find bits of filamentous algae on the leaf so it could be something aquatic?). I will provide both pictures and if I can, the videos I took of it. It has a spring shaped tail that seems to connect it to the edge of the leaf that's causing it to spring back rapidly after it moves out from the leaf.[image: x40 lens][image: x10 lens][link to the pics shown as well as the videos taken at the same lens strengths as well as other stuff I found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDa6V.jpg)

EDIT: I am from Michigan, and based off of a lab that I'm doing today in the same class the plant is an Elodea, a freshwater aquatic plant. Don't know if that info helps any but hopefully it does!

Comment: Welcome lilgyz. Could you give us a bit more to go on such as what country/area you're living in, what type of plant was the leaf from, perhaps a picture of the whole leaf?

Comment: I'm from michigan. Unfortuantely I don't know what kind of plant it is nor did I get a picture of the plant but I can if I can figure out what plant it was